# sql sum duplicated rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I made a query like this:

```
SELECT nr_budynku, nr_pokoju, count (DISTINCT nr_szafy) AS count
FROM szafa
INNER JOIN szafa_miejsce_przechowywania ON szafa.id = szafa_miejsce_przechowywania.id_szafa
INNER JOIN miejsce_przechowywania ON szafa_miejsce_przechowywania.id_miejsce_przechowywania = miejsce_przechowywania.id
GROUP BY nr_budynku, nr_pokoju, nr_szafy;
```

query gave me this result:

```
 nr_budynku | nr_pokoju | count
------------+-----------+-------
 1          |        25 |     1
 1          |        25 |     1
 1          |       123 |     1
 2          |       122 |     1
```

but I wanted this:

```
 nr_budynku | nr_pokoju | count
------------+-----------+-------
 1          |        25 |     2
 1          |       123 |     1
 2          |       122 |     1
```

What is wrong with this query?
I tried something with sum function but it was even worse.
I work on postgres
id in szafa is my primary key but nr_szafy in szafa is describing the number of wardrobe, in my example database id are from 1 to 10 but nr_szafy is from 1 to 4.

Comment: Remove `nr_szafy` from the `group by`

Comment: thx that helped me a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT nr_budynku, nr_pokoju, count (nr_szafy) as count
FROM szafa
INNER JOIN szafa_miejsce_przechowywania ON szafa.id = szafa_miejsce_przechowywania.id_szafa
INNER JOIN miejsce_przechowywania ON szafa_miejsce_przechowywania.id_miejsce_przechowywania = miejsce_przechowywania.id
group by nr_budynku, nr_pokoju;
```

remove `nr_szafy` from group by.